# add user submitted question to String[] in seperate activity (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a user submitted question to a String[] in a separate activity.

Im about two weeks in on learning app development with android and any help would be greatly appreciated.[User submission page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa9Oc.png)

how do I add the "enter text here" to the public  String[] questions = new String []

what I have so far is

--Submission Page--

```
EditText userText;
EditText drunkOrKid;

private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton radioButton;
private Button btnDisplay;



public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    RadioButton radioDerek = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioDrunk);
    RadioButton radioStephen = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioKid);

    // Is the current Radio Button checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioDrunk:
            if (checked)

                drunkOrKid.setText("true");

            break;

        case R.id.radioKid:
            if (checked)

                drunkOrKid.setText("false");

            break;


    }
}
```

-- QUESTION storage page --

public class questions extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);
}



public  String[] questions = new String [] {
        "I went to go see an animated film in a movie theater. I screamed warnings to the main character for the duration of the movie, because I feared if I didn't she wouldn't realize the danger she was in.",
        "I raced a friend for shotgun (front seat) of the car and they slammed open the door on my head and split my forehead open",
        "Late at night, I got up and ran around screaming about how I needed the \"sticky notes\" and then proceeded to vomit.",
        "Chugged orange cough syrup because I thought it was OJ",
        "I peed in the middle of the high way while no cars were passing by.",
        "I dropped four cookies into a grand piano at a college recital.",
        "I broke into a safe because I wasn't in a mindset where I realized it was illegal. I then told the people whose safe it was \"I broke into your safe!\"",
        "Shot myself in the hand with an arrow. Didn’t notice until I looked down at my hand. Yanked it out, ran inside yelling about there was a hole in my hand.",
        "At a friend's house. Ended up naked under the table, crying, because I didn't want to go home.",
        "I woke up in the dead of night, walked downstairs, out the back door, and peed on the swingset in the backyard",
        "Thought about something that was supposed to be kept a secret during a conversation. Didn't actually tell anyone. But began panicking over the fact that I might have. Eventually got so stressed I had to leave the conversation altogether, leaving my peers very confused.",
        "I ran down the street in just my underwear. I ran around for about 30 minutes before someone caught me and took me back to my house.",
        "Took off my pants and got naked in the middle of a bunch of people. Didn't realise I'd done anything wrong until I was *told* so.",
        "I went to a brand new shopping center in my town, i decided to fuck around and play in the fountain, where i proceeded to fall in.",
        "Went into a store to buy something after being to the super market, but tried to pay with cookies instead of cash",
        "Decided I could most certainly jump over 3 of my friends on the stairs, fell, broke a bone and cried until I was carried to the car",
        "got attached to ball of string and cried for 3 hours straight after leaving it behind",
        "Nearly started a house fire by spraying aerosol deodorant at the flame of a candle to see what it would do and paper was directly behind it",
        "Nearly suffocated while hanging by the collar of my t-shirt from a high fence. Afterwards claimed to look like a frog for the whole situation.",
        "After a football(soccer) game where I was the keeper and couldn’t keep any goals I fell asleep on a small wooden bench in a locker room filled with kids changing clothes while there was loud hardcore music playing.",
        "Was with my brother one night and he claimed I hit him in the head with a 2x4 and when I was asked why I hit him with a 2x4 I said I didn’t hit him with a 2x4... I hit him with a 2x6",



};



public  boolean[] answers = new boolean[]{
        true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, true, false,
};
```

}

]

Answer (score 0):

Your string array already has a set size. Why not use Collections instead? Say, an **ArrayList**? you can add new objects to the List.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing array to a list or array list and make it static in that class.

```
ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
questions.add("");
questions.add("");
...
```

Once you define an array, you cant add more values to it so you need a more collections oriented object.  If you make it static in that class, and some static functions for manipulation. You can add new values, or get the current values from anywhere in your app.

If you are just using that class for storing arrays of data you dont need all that activity stuff.